# What is the purpose of the fontSize theme setting when all typography variants are `rem`?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, typography

The documentation for Material UI Typography settings (https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/typography/) are confusing and don't really make sense:

> MUI uses rem units for the font size. The browser  element
> default font size is 16px, but browsers have an option to change this
> value, so rem units allow us to accommodate the user's settings,
> resulting in a better accessibility support. Users change font size
> settings for all kinds of reasons, from poor eyesight to choosing
> optimum settings for devices that can be vastly different in size and
> viewing distance.
>
> To change the font-size of MUI you can provide a fontSize property.
> The default value is 14px.

So which is it? It uses REM or use the font-size as a base for the typography variants?  If you look at the default theme (https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/default-theme/?expand-path=$.typography) all the variants are supposed to use `rem` -- and the documents even talk about customizing this value in `htmlFontSize`.

So I'm really struggling to understand the use/purpose for the `fontSize` theme setting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `typography.fontSize` and `typography.htmlFontSize` values are expected to be in pixels but those pixel values do not get put directly onto the page. Instead, the material ui code will take the pixel value and calculate a corresponding `rem` value. That `rem` value is what gets put into the css class, and thus rendered by the browser. By using `rem`s as the final value, the user's browser settings can change the final size

The equation they use for this calculation is show [in the article](https://mui.com/static/images/font-size.svg):

> computed = specification * (typography.fontSize / 14) * (html fontsize / typography.htmlFontSize)

Example 1: everything is set to its defaults, with `typography.fontSize` set to `14`, `typography.htmlFontSize` set to 16, and `typography.h3.fontSize` set to `"1.2rem"`. You then render a `<Typography variant="h3">`. In that case, the calculation would be:

> computed = 1.2rem * (14 / 14) * (16 / 16)

This works out to having a size of `1.2rem`, and that's what will be put into the css class.

Example 2: You now changed `typography.fontSize` to `12`, `typography.htmlFontSize` to  `18`, and `typography.h3.fontSize` to `"1.5rem"`. With those values, the calculation will be:

> computed = 1.5rem * (12 / 14) * (16 / 18)

This works out to about `1.143 rem`.

In practice, if you want to change all your fonts to be bigger or smaller, change `typography.fontSize`; each variant will scale based on that. If you want to change a specific variant to be bigger while leaving the rest the same, then modify `typography.[variant].fontSize`. I don't see a reason you would want to change `typography.htmlFontSize`, but that knob is available if you need it.

Comment: But the theme object doesn't expect values in pixels. All of the default typography variants are designed in `rem`. REM is derived from the `htmlFontSize` value (in turn which is set on `html` element (if you so want to mess with that setting beyond the browser default.) -- I already know this. unfortunately it doesn't help answer what the point of the `fontSize` property is in the typography part of the theme.

Comment: 'The theme object expects values to be in pixels' - Where does this hold true or where is it stated?

Comment: `But the theme object doesn't expect values in pixels` For `typography.fontSize` and `typography.htmlFontSize` it does. I should have been more clear that those are the values i was talking about. I've updated my answer with examples of the calculation.

Comment: I saw the equation, but I didn't really get what they were trying to do. Now I'm just confused what they're trying to achieve with this. For me, this is bizarre. By all means use `rem` as a relative size, but this pixel value to `fontSize` is at best, confusing, and at worst, completely unnecessary. Why would they do this?

It could just be `HTML size * rem specification`. Done?

Comment: And thank you -- it helps me understand how it's used, but I'll be damned if it's not pointless

Comment: Think of `typography.fontSize` as being in charge of "what does 1rem mean?". So if you put a value of 16, then you're saying that anywhere that uses `"1rem"` should be 16 pixels high (assuming the user hasn't tweaked their browser settings), and anywhere that uses `"2rem"` should be 32 pixels high, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Code from **node_modules@mui\material\styles\createTypography.js**

```
const coef = fontSize / 14;
const pxToRem = pxToRem2 || (size => `${size / htmlFontSize * coef}rem`);

  const buildVariant = (fontWeight, size, lineHeight, letterSpacing, casing) => _extends({
    fontFamily,
    fontWeight,
    fontSize: pxToRem(size),
    // Unitless following https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/
    lineHeight
  }, fontFamily === defaultFontFamily ? {
    letterSpacing: `${round(letterSpacing / size)}em`
  } : {}, casing, allVariants);

  const variants = {
    h1: buildVariant(fontWeightLight, 96, 1.167, -1.5),
    h2: buildVariant(fontWeightLight, 60, 1.2, -0.5),
    h3: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 48, 1.167, 0),
    h4: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 34, 1.235, 0.25),
    h5: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 24, 1.334, 0),
    h6: buildVariant(fontWeightMedium, 20, 1.6, 0.15),
    subtitle1: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 16, 1.75, 0.15),
    subtitle2: buildVariant(fontWeightMedium, 14, 1.57, 0.1),
    body1: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 16, 1.5, 0.15),
    body2: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 14, 1.43, 0.15),
    button: buildVariant(fontWeightMedium, 14, 1.75, 0.4, caseAllCaps),
    caption: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 12, 1.66, 0.4),
    overline: buildVariant(fontWeightRegular, 12, 2.66, 1, caseAllCaps)
  };
```

[Px to rem mui function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGKYN.png)

this is what I found in the MUI module.

So, from the function **buildVariant** I can say it expected font sizes in pixels and converts them into rem values per variant.

to achieve your desired font size per variant you can add values in px using a custom function without changing htmlFontSize(16px).

```
const calcFontSize = (expectedBodyFontSize)=>{
    return (14/16)*expectedBodyFontSize
}
```

Whatever it returns you just have to assign it as font-size to create theme variable like below

```
const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: calcFontSize(14),
  },
});
```

If you will check the body tag font size it will be of 14px.